# how to correct leastsq() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x0'

Tags: python

```py
A= df4["v_Acc"]                                         #Output of the model
a=1.5                                              # Acceleration parameter
v=df4["v_Vel"]                                        # Current speed
vo=20                                                # desired speed
s=df4["Space_Headway"]                               # Actual distance
so=2.0                                                # minimum distance gap
del_v=df4["v_Vel"]-df4["leader_Vel"]            # relative speed =V_f - V_l
b=2.0                                             # comfortable deceleration
T=1                                                            # time gap
delta=4                                                 # Acceleration Exponent
import math

sx = so + v*T + (v*del_v)/(2* math.pow(a*b,0.5))                        # desired distance 
def residual(a,vo,so,b,T,A,v,del_v,s,delta):
     model = a(1-((v/vo)**delta- ((sx/s)**2)))
     return model-A


from scipy.optimize import leastsq
out = leastsq(residual, args=(a,vo,so,b,T,A,v,del_v,s,delta) )
```

I am trying to calibrate the IDM model with the NGSIM data. I was trying to find the values of the parameter `a`, `b`, `T`, `so`, `vo` by taking the initial guess as shown. However I am not able to find the error in my least square method. What wrong am I doing here

Comment: Take a look the function signature: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
v=df4["v_Vel"].to_numpy()
s=df4["Space_Headway"].to_numpy()
del_v=(df4["v_Vel"]-df4["leader_Vel"]).to_numpy()
A= df4["v_Acc"].to_numpy()

def fcn2min(params, v,s,del_v, A):
    vo = params['vo']
    T  = params['T']
    so = params['so']
    a = params['a']
    b = params['b']
    sx = so + v*T + (v*del_v)/(2*(math.sqrt(a*b)))
    model = a*(1-((v/vo)**4- ((sx/s)**2)))
    return (model-A) 

from lmfit import Minimizer, Parameters, report_fit
params = Parameters()
params.add('vo', value=12,min=10,max=30)
params.add('T', value=1.2,min=1,max=5)
params.add('so', value=2.5,min=2,max=6)
params.add('a', value=2.1,min=2,max=6)
params.add('b', value=0.5,min=0.5,max=4)


minner = Minimizer(fcn2min, params, fcn_args=(v,s,del_v,A))
res=minner.minimize()
```